# "Undefined" value from imported function, need value to use in React app

Tags: javascript, reactjs, worker, papaparse

In a React app, I'm trying to load a JavaScript function from another script, pass it some information and have it process it and return the result. It is currently not working because the processing happens on a worker thread, and it seems like the result is being used before the worker finishes, giving a `undefined` value in my app.

Inside the function, I have some console.logs that show that the result is successfully obtained. It's just not being passed back to the script. It's being ignored.

How can I get the result to show up in App.js?

I have replicated this problem in a sandbox [here](https://codesandbox.io/s/goofy-dew-gydxz?file=/src/addressParser.js).

The console.log statements:

```
(addressParser) creating layer: addresses 
(createLayers) addresses: undefined 
(addressParser) done creating layer: addresses 
(addressParser) addresses: [object Object]
```

app.js:

```js
import "./styles.css";
import layers from "./createLayers.js";

export default function App() {
  return (
    <div className="App" layers={layers}>
      {Object.entries(layers).map(([name, layer]) => {
        return (
          <div>
            <span>Name: {name}</span>
            <br />
            <span>Data: {name.data ? "success": "failed"}</span>
          </div>
        );
      })}
    </div>
  );
}
```

createLayers.js:

```js
import Data from "./metadata.json";
import load from "./addressParser.js";

var layers = {};
createLayers();

function createLayers() {
  Object.keys(Data).forEach(function (name) {
    layers[name] = load(name, Data[name]);
    console.log("(createLayers) addresses: " + layers[name]);
  });
}

export default layers;
```

addressParser.js:

```js
import { readRemoteFile } from "react-papaparse";

function load(name, metadata) {
  console.log("(addressParser) creating layer: " + name);

  readRemoteFile(metadata.url, {
    header: true,
    worker: true,
    complete: (results) => {
      /* header: true makes it into an array of objects */
      if (!results) {
        console.log("COULD NOT CREATE LAYER: " + name);
        return;
      }

      var layer = { ...metadata, data: results };

      console.log("(addressParser) done creating layer: " + name);
      console.log("(addressParser) addresses: " + results);
      return layer;
    }
  });
}

export default load;
```

metadata.json:

```
{
  "addresses": {
    "url": "https://raw.githubusercontent.com/FBosler/Medium-Data-Extraction/master/sales_team.csv"
  }
}
```

One dependency: react-papaparse.

Comment: 1. You don't return anything from your load function. 2. It seems to be asynchronous anyways.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I return the response from an asynchronous call?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14220321/how-do-i-return-the-response-from-an-asynchronous-call)

Comment: There's a `return layer;` statement.

Comment: Yes, in a callback, not the load function. You don't return anything from the outer `load` function, so the return value defaults to `undefined`.

Comment: Should I be returning a value or callback from the outer `load` function?

Comment: You probably want to return a Promise that is resolved in the callback, see the answers on the linked duplicate for more detail.